# What type of an engine is a Carnot engine?

Tags: thermodynamics

If a Carnot engine was practically possible, what type of an engine would it be, and in which field it would be used? Is it a powerful engine or not?

Comment: Depends on how technical you want to get, I suppose -- what technically is a "Carnot" engine and what isn't.  I recall my grandfather having a small engine -- about the size of the proverbial toaster -- which operated by placing it on a heat source (such as a gas kitchen stove).  And I recall reading of similar (but larger) engines being used in industry, to power some process where extending the factory's jackshaft to the spot was not feasible.  Of course, electric motors (and, in some cases, batteries) took away this "market".

Comment: @HotLicks Sounds like a [Stirling engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine).  To answers your hypothetical about what technically is a "Carnot" and what is not; see the [comparison of ideal heat engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine#Heat_engine_processes).  The cycles undergo different types of processes in each engine.

Comment: @JMac - Yeah, "Stirling" -- I couldn't remember the term.

Answer (score 3):

the carnot engine is an imaginary device which runs on heat furnished by a high temperature source from which it extracts the maximum possible amount of useful work without losses of any kind, and then rejects the remaining unuseable heat to a cold temperature sink.

For example, it might be an engine in which a fuel is burned to boil a working fluid into vapor, which then might either spin a turbine through its expansion or push a piston connected to a crankshaft to allow useful work to be extracted. That work might then be used to spin a generator and furnish electrical power, or propel a vehicle- but these details do not matter, because it does not exist as a functioning device; it is instead a theoretical construct which serves as an ideal standard against which the performance of all other heat engines can be compared.

If real, it would be the most powerful and efficient heat engine mathematically possible, but as devised it could not be built- because in the real world out there, frictional losses, temperature gradients, and heat leakage will always be present.

There are heat engines which come close to the carnot efficiency through careful design, and their descriptions can be studied in any undergraduate engineering thermodynamics textbook.

Comment: -1 Does not answer the question.

Comment: @sammygerbil, see edits. -NN